# Why my sitemap doesn't have any link pages after generated?

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap

I am a new web developer I tried to create sitmemap with my website, First I went to website https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ then put my url site everykh.com and clicked button start then I downloaded sitemap.xml file and previewed in notepad.Here is my site map all code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset
      xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9
            http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd">
<!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com -->

</urlset>
```

Why my sitemap doesn't have any link pages after generated ?

And after I submited my sitemap.xml file then preview http://everykh.com/sitemap.xml , has error as below.

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
      <urlset xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9             http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"><!-- created with Free Online Sitemap Generator www.xml-sitemaps.com 
--></urlset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your website is dynamic website so websites like xmlsitemaps.com can not crawl it. you will have to ask you developer to create the sitemap.

please read this for more info.
https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html